How to Share NextAuth.js Session Token Across Subdomains in Next.js
I’m using Next.js and NextAuth.js in my project, which includes multiple subdomains. For authentication, I’m using the Credentials Provider in NextAuth.js. On login, Next.js stores the session in a cookie named next-auth.session-token.
Here’s the issue:
I want this session token (next-auth.session-token) to be accessible across all valid subdomains. For example, if the user logs in on www.mydomain.com, the session cookie should also be available for subdomains like courses.mydomain.com, mentor.mydomain.com, and mentee.mydomain.com.
I’ve tried configuring the cookie options in the next-auth configuration, but I haven’t been able to make it work.

Setting the cookie.domain explicitly in the NextAuth.js options:

route.ts file
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

const nextAuthUrl = process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL!;

const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    cookies: {
        sessionToken: {
            name: `${nextAuthUrl.startsWith("https://") ? "__Secure-" : ""}next-auth.session-token`,
            options: {
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: "lax",
                path: "/",
                domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? ".example.com" : ".localhost",
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            },
        },
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: {
                    label: "Username",
                    type: "text",
                    placeholder: "your username",
                },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const { username, password, role } = credentials as {
                    username: string;
                    password: string;
                    role: string;
                };

                if (username !== "admin" && password !== "admin") {
                    return null;
                }

                const user = {
                    id: "9001",
                    name: username,
                    email: "admin@example.com",
                    accessToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    role,
                };

                return user;
            },
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
        }),
        FacebookProvider({
            clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET!,
        }),
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.id = user.id;
                token.email = user.email;
                token.accessToken = user.accessToken;
                token.role = user.role;
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session }) {
            return session;
        },
    },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token = await getToken({ req: request, cookieName: 'next-auth.session-token' });

  const sessionToken = request.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token")?.value || "";

  const nextAuthUrl = process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL!

  const hostname = request.headers.get('host') || "";
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;


  // Define domain-specific rules
  const mainDomain = "www.example.com";
  const subdomains = ["courses.example.com", "mentor.example.com", "mentee.example.com"];
  const subdomainsLocalhost = ["courses.localhost:3000", "mentor.localhost:3000", "mentee.localhost:3000"];
  const userRoles = ['courses', 'mentor', 'mentee']

  // Define routes
  const authRoutes = ["/login", "/register"];
  const protectedRoutes = ["/dashboard"];
  const publicLandingPages = ["/"];

  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.some((route) => pathname.startsWith(route));
  const isProtectedRoute = protectedRoutes.some((route) => pathname.startsWith(route));
  const isPublicLandingPage = publicLandingPages.some((route) => pathname === route);
  const mainDomainLoginPage =
    hostname.includes("localhost") ? "http://localhost:3000/login" : "maindomain";

  if (isPublicLandingPage) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }
  // Main domain logic 
  if (hostname === mainDomain || hostname.split('.')[0].includes("localhost")) {

    if (token) {
      const role = token.role as string; // Ensure `role` is included in your token payload
      if (userRoles.includes(role) && (isAuthRoute || isProtectedRoute)) {
        const redirectSubdomain = hostname.includes("localhost")
          ? `http://${role}.localhost:3000/dashboard`
          : `https://${role}.example.com/dashboard`;

        // Set cookie to share across subdomains
        const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL(redirectSubdomain, request.url));

        // Configure the cookie for subdomains
        response.cookies.set(`${nextAuthUrl.startsWith('https://') ? "__Secure-" : ""}next-auth.session-token`, sessionToken, {
          domain: role + '.localhost',
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: 'lax',
          path: '/',
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        }
        );
        return response;
      }
    }
  }

  if (subdomains.includes(hostname) || subdomainsLocalhost.includes(hostname)) {
    console.log("Subdomain logic triggered");


    if (token && isAuthRoute) {
      const role = token.role as string; // Ensure `role` is included in your token payload
      if (userRoles.includes(role)) {
        const redirectSubdomain = hostname.includes("localhost")
          ? `http://${role}.localhost:3000/dashboard`
          : `https://${role}.example.com/dashboard`;

        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(redirectSubdomain, request.url))
      }
    }

    // Redirect to login if accessing protected routes without a token
    if (isProtectedRoute && !token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(mainDomainLoginPage, request.url));
    }
  }

  // Fallback: Redirect to login for protected routes without a token
  if (isProtectedRoute && !token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(mainDomainLoginPage, request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/dashboard/:path*",
    "/login",
    "/register",
    "/",
  ],
}


Adjusting sameSite to None and ensuring the cookie has the Secure flag for HTTPS.
Debugging with different subdomain setups locally (e.g., using localhost with subdomains like courses.localhost:3000).

